# Using ogr2ogr to save KML file including styling of lines/other features

Tags: kml, ogr2ogr

I am trying to create an automatic procedure for using ogr2ogr to read a PostGIS table and output a KML file containing line features. 
However, I need to define the styling of these lines including both width and color. Potentially I could save the styling information as attributes if that could help.

Is this possible with ogr2ogr?

Comment: It may happen automatically if you add a field named "OGR_STYLE" into your table in PostGIS and fill it with drawing instructions as described in http://www.gdal.org/ogr_feature_style.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer this question myself.
As the comment by user30184 mentions, you can use a field named "OGR_STYLE" to define the styling for your features. I could not get this to work with point features, but it worked well with line features. 
For example:

```
OGR_STYLE: PEN(c:#b3ff00,w:2.5px)
```